# File.getName() not comparing properly to a String

Tags: java, string, if-statement, arraylist

I have an arrayList in a class and a getter for it. I need to make a method that returns an arrayList filled with all the files from the first arrayList that have the same name as the String arg. This is what I've come up with.

```
ArrayList<File> dirs = new ArrayList<File>(); // filled with files

public ArrayList<File> getDirectoriesNamed(String fileName) {
    ArrayList<File> files = new ArrayList<File>();
    for (File file : dirs) {
        if (file.getName() == fileName) //problem is here
            files.add(file);
    }
    return files;
}
```

however when I try this, I get an empty arrayList. and I figured out that the reason is because of the if Statement... is there any reason why that shouldn't work that I'm not seeing?

Comment: I just realized that this question is a big time duplicate...

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing two Strings with '==', use `file.getName().equals(fileName)`

Comment: Just flag as duplicate.

Comment: Down voted because I have answered the correct answer but the question is a duplicate? Seems a bit unfair doesn't it?

Comment: Yes it does, that's why I only left you a comment. However many people here very much frown upon answering questions like this that get asked many times per day and are (to most people) obvious duplicates.

Answer (score -1):

Two things...

1) Make sure you include the extensions, e.g filename.txt as you String fileName.

2) Objects should be compared with .equals() if it's a string and you are worried about caps there is .equalsIgnoreCase(). I am pretty sure == is not the issue for you here even though objects should be compared differently == in java does work for some string objects. NOTE that just because it works doesn't mean it is right.

Comment: the extensions weren't a problem, but thanks for the .equals(). that helps.